# Can't pipe into diff?

Tags: command-line, pipe, diff

I wanted to be clever and compare a remote file to a local file without first manually downloading it. I can get the contents of the remote file by

```
ssh user@remote-host "cat path/file.name"
```

However, piping that to `diff`

```
ssh user@remote-host "cat path/file.name" | diff path/file.name
```

gives me this:

```
diff: missing operand after `path/file.nae'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

I have ssh keys set up, so it's not prompting me for a password. What's a workaround for this?

Comment: By the way, you're still downloading the file when you do this (since its content gets sent over the SSH connection), you're just not saving it anywhere. So it's not like you save any bandwidth or anything.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want to muck up my file system with one-shot files hanging around.

Comment: for when the command does not support stdin (e.g. via `-`), you can use `/dev/stdin`. e.g. `diff file1 /dev/stdin`

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use  `-` to represent the standard input:

```
ssh user@remote-host "cat path/file.name" | diff path/file.name -
```

Comment: What if both files are fetched via ssh?

Answer (score 89):

Here's one workaround: `diff` seems to accept <(*expr*) as arguemnts:

```
diff <(ssh \"cat path/file.name/") <(cat path/file.name)
```

Comment: That's not diff, that's the shell (bash, ksh and zsh support this syntax, but it's not POSIX), with some help from the kernel (it must provide `/dev/fd`: `diff` sees something like `/dev/fd/3` on its command line).

Comment: It doesn't "must provide" - shells can create temporary named pipes for this feature too.

Comment: this is the coolest answer!

Comment: I personally prefer this answer. I needed to diff two different XML files; but they needed to be properly formed first. That led to this: `diff -y <(xmllint --format "${1}") <(xmllint --format "${2}")` which I now use all the time.

Comment: This is also very useful on OS X where one might want to compare two binary .plist files: `diff <(plutil -convert xml1 -o -- "${1}") <(plutil -convert xml1 -o - -- "${2}")`

Comment: My zsh reports `error: /dev/fd/11: unsupported file type
fatal: cannot hash /dev/fd/11` but that is because it uses `git diff`. Running `command diff ...` instead gives no trouble.

Comment: This is less portable though. It [won't work on all systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/750855/38514). Also, there's no sense in doing `<(cat path/file.name)` instead of just `path/file.name`

Answer (score 3):

Piping into diff is equivalent to running

`diff path/file.name`

and then, once it's running, typing the entire contents of the file.

As you can see, that's not what you expected.

Comment: No workaround? :(

Comment: Look at Hemant's answer. I didn't know of one.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff /tmp/localtempfile <(ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@server "cat /tmp/remotetempfile")
```

Comment: What is with the lowering of security `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`? Otherwise a good answer.