# Portable temporary file descriptors inside `sh -c`

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors, subshell

```
cat <(echo yes)
```

Displays "yes". And running this inside `sh -m` results in the same thing on Bash 5.2.15.

Yet on Bash 4.4.20 it throws an error:

```
sh -c "cat <(echo yes)"
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Why the error?

Are there any other ways `sh -c` differs from running `sh` and then typing the command?

Comment: Is `sh` bash in both cases? If the list of differences is given in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode (which may vary from version to version, check the installed documentation to see for each version). If it's some other shell that's sh, there will be other differences.

Comment: `echo yes`, `echo yes | cat` and `echo yes | cat /dev/stdin` also output `yes`, can you give a more relevant example of why you'd need to use ksh-style process substitution.

Comment: `sh` is a link to `dash` in my linucies (is that the plural of linux?) - what is it in yours?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular shell"?  `sh` is generally a POSIX-compliant shell, so you shouldn't expect it to understand the extra features of other shells.  It seems you have the world backward, thinking of `sh` as an exception rather than as the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run Bash as `sh`, it starts in POSIX mode, which disables some nonstandard features, including process substitution in versions before Bash 5.1. From the `CHANGES` file in the distribution:

```
This document details the changes between this version, bash-5.1-alpha, and
the previous version, bash-5.0-release.

3. New Features in Bash

u. Process substitution is now available in posix mode.
```

The fact that it works in the most recent versions is likely the reason it's not listed in the [reference manual page on POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html).

Note that on many systems, `sh` is not Bash at all. If you want Bash, run `bash`.